# SAS Remove Outliers

Tags: sas, outliers

I'm looking for a macro or something in SAS that can help me in isolating the outliers from a dataset. I define an outlier as: Upperbound: Q3+1.5(IQR) Lowerbound: Q1-1.5(IQR). I have the following SAS code:

```
title 'Fall 2015';
proc univariate data = fall2015 freq;
var enrollment_count;
histogram enrollment_count / vscale = percent vaxis = 0 to 50 by 5 midpoints = 0 to 300 by 5;
inset n mean std max min range / position = ne;
run;
```

I would like to get rid of the outliers from fall2015 dataset. I found some macros, but no luck in working the macro. Several have a class variable which I don't have. Any ideas how to separate my data?

Comment: There is no standard definition of an outlier. You need to define your rules and then you can filter out the observations. What is an outlier, is a question that probably belongs on stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Cool.  I'm looking for a simple macro that would do find the following outliers based on this definition: Upperbound: Q3+1.5(IQR) Lowerbound: Q1-1.5(IQR).

Comment: You can modify the code here but its not an efficient method. https://gist.github.com/statgeek/31316a678433a1db8136

Answer (score 0):

Here's a macro I wrote a while ago to do this, under slightly different rules. I've modified it to meet your criteria (1.5).

1. Use proc means to calculate Q1/Q3 and IQR (QRANGE)
2. Build Macro to cap based on rules
3. Call macro using call execute and boundaries set, using the output from step 1.

   ```
   *Calculate IQR and first/third quartiles;
   proc means data=sashelp.class stackods n qrange p25 p75;
   var weight height;
   ods output summary=ranges;
   run;

   *create data with outliers to check;
   data capped; 
       set sashelp.class;
       if name='Alfred' then weight=220;
       if name='Jane' then height=-30;
   run;

   *macro to cap outliers;

   %macro cap(dset=,var=, lower=, upper=);

   data &dset;
       set &dset;
       if &var>&upper then &var=&upper;
       if &var<&lower then &var=&lower;
   run;

   %mend;


   *create cutoffs and execute macro for each variable;
   data cutoffs;
   set ranges;
   lower=p25-1.5*qrange;
   upper=p75+1.5*qrange;
   string = catt('%cap(dset=capped, var=', variable, ", lower=", lower, ", upper=", upper ,");");
   call execute(string);
   run;
   ```

Comment: Can you tell me where data capped comes in? Lower and upper in the macro, are these confidences?  thx.

Comment: Data capped is generated as a sample. Its used in the macro execution in the last data null step that executes the macro. You should be able to run the code as is to help trace issues.